# How can i save the value of search field of datatable and the use it in another page?

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to send with POST the value of the field "search" of datatable to use it to initialize another page , it is possible ?
i try in thi way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var table = $('#elencoprodotti').DataTable( {

    "language": {
        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Italian.json",
        "decimal": ",",
        "thousands": "."
    },
    "ajax": {
        "url": modulo+"_get_elenco.php?tabella=",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "IMG" },
        { "data": "CODICE" },
        { "data": "CODICE_OBSOLETO" },
        { "data": "DESCRIZIONE" },
        { "data": "CATEGORIA" },
        { "data": "FORNITORE" },
        { "data": "UM_BREVE" },
        { "data": "QTA_NEW" },
        { "data": "SCORTA_MINIMA" }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        { 

            "targets": [0],
            "searchable": false, // disabilita la ricereca per il campo con indice 0
            "orderable": false // disabilita l'ordinamento4

        },
```

this was my code and i added this function on change and i set the value of the filter in a variable , but now i can't send it by post

```
$('#elencoprodotti').on('change', function() {
    var value = $('.dataTables_filter input').val();
    //alert(value); // <-- the value
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        method:"POST",
        url: "ciao.php",
        data:{ 'value': value},
        success: function(){
            alert(value);

    }


    });
```

and ciao.php is just

```
    $name = $_POST['value'];
echo $name;
```

Comment: you can try to catch the value of the datatable search box using onblur

Comment: So what is happening now?

Comment: @RiggsFolly now i have an error: "Undefined index: value "

Comment: @hungrykoala i just catch the value my problem is send it with POST

Comment: so `alert(value);` is working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('.dataTables_filter input').on('blur', function() {
    var search_value = $('.dataTables_filter input').val();
      $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url: "ciao.php",
        data:{ "value":search_value},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
});
```

Remove `type:"POST",` it's not necessary. You also need to add a parameter to your success function since you won't be able to get the result otherwise.

Also, variables should be specific so I changed `value` to `search_value`.

Comment: sorry I expressed myself badly also the alert doesn't work in my opinion is all the $.ajax({ that it's wrong but i don't know how.. because with 
 var search_value = $('.dataTables_filter input').val();  i catch the value and i can add it correctly to the url and then got it in GET, but i don't want that my search is visible in the url

Comment: @Jordan.M I've updated it to watch `.dataTables_filter input` and using `blur` to check for changes. Since you mentioned that you can get the data using `$('.dataTables_filter input').val()`

Comment: @Jordan.M What I meant with alert is the first alert just below `$('.dataTables_filter input').val()`.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event on the search input instead for the task to work.

**Try this:**

```
$('.dataTables_filter input').on('change keyup paste', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  alert(value); // <-- the value
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ciao.php",
    data: {
      'value': value
    },
    success: function() {
      alert(value);

    }
  });
});
```

In ciao.php - you can save the passed value to a session variable so you can use it again in another page.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it doesn't work value is also not set in POST

Comment: Make sure my code is below the `$('#elencoprodotti').DataTable(.....);` block for it to work.